# Gradle with Spring Boot is trying to unzip a POM

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I have a project that uses Spring Boot 2.0.1 and depends on another project that is using Spring Boot 1.5.3.

When I build a Standalone Jar I get an error that Gradle cannot unzip a POM file.

```
Execution failed for task ':stubs:fatJar'.
> Could not expand ZIP '/Users/myusername/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies/1.5.3.RELEASE/2c172c7484dae0a4190847f98d619a0221d3a849/spring-boot-dependencies-1.5.3.RELEASE.pom'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just exclude the Spring dependencies from the project using the old version of Spring Boot.

```
compile('com.mycompany.api:my-api:1.0.20') {
    exclude(module: 'spring-boot-dependencies')
    exclude(module: 'spring-boot-starter-web')
}
```